# How can I fix my loose toilet seat?

Tags: toilet

I have a toilet seat that has little by little, become very loose. I have searched the internet and found I had to tighten the two twisting things underneath the toilet bowl, in the back.

They are twisted / welded shut and always have been. If I manually jiggle the toilet seat, it feels as though the heads of the screws in the backs are firm, but the toilet itself is not locked to them. The toilet seat itself won't come off and only wobbles on the horizontal plane.

Comment: are you sure the top covers over the mounting bolts don't open? There has to be some access to both sides of the bolt to install/ remove the seat and tighten it.

Comment: It would help if we knew the toilet manufacturer and number. Look at the underside of the water tank lid for these. It might also help if you look at the picture on this site: http://home.howstuffworks.com/home-improvement/plumbing/how-to-repair-a-toilet1.htm.

Comment: Gonna check when I get at home.